# Swift application crash after upgrading to latest XCode beta 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

I just updated to XCode Beta 3 and I had to change every single array in the application because arrays are now defined differently than before. But I do not think this is the problem. The application runs with no compile errors or warnings.

The application crash here:

```
extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {

        // CRASH
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks")

        var sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as GameScene
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    }
}
```

What has happend?

Comment: What is the crash message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cleaning out the build folder

You can do it from the Products menu while holding <kbd>ALT</kbd>.
Or by using the <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> keyboard shortcut